# Should I use "with" or "from" in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

> “I might be light, but I’m strong. Thanks to the exercise I get **with/from**
>   my weight vests.”

What's the correct option and why?

Comment: There are many contexts where more than one preposition can be used. This looks like one of them.

Comment: Both are at the very least "acceptable" (as would be ***through***, and possibly other prepositions), but my guess is ***from*** would be far more common overall.

Comment: I would use *lightweight*, not *light*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of your possible phrases are correct and understandable

> Thanks to the exercise I get **with** my weight vests.
>   Thanks to the exercise I get **from** my weight vests.

and as @J.R. points out either can be used.

Personally, I would use

> Thanks to the exercise I get **with** my weight vests.

since the expression is usually said

> exercise **with** weights

and not

> exercise **from** weights

whereas

> Thanks to the exercise I get **from** my workout.

can be used to show a different type of relationship for attribution.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, you could make a good grammatical argument for either.  The difference is the *nuance* between the two.

"**With** my weight vest" emphasizes the word *exercise* because *with* implies that you and your vest exercised *together* -- that you exercised and the weight vest helped.  But "**from** my weight vest" puts the emphasis back on *strong*, as the result of exercise which you *received* from using the weight vest.  It reinforces the idea that the weight vest is primarily *responsible* for the gain, that the exercise alone would not have been enough.

In this way it's not much different from the more common distinction between with/from.  Example:

> I got the eggs *with* my sister
>   I got the eggs *from* my sister

The first implies that we got the eggs together, while the second says that my sister is the *source* of the eggs.  Both are valid, it just depends on what you want to say.